# How to integrate search in my nativescript app

Tags: elasticsearch, nativescript, algolia, angular2-nativescript

I am building a nativescript app that requires a search functionality. I am using firebase for my backend and  I would ideally like to use a hosted search service like algolia for the same - however the algolia-search and algolia-search-helper plugins required are not supported in nativescript. I am open to using other search services like elasticsearch too, but am not sure how to go about it.

Any suggestions on how I can implement search in my nativescript app would be great.

Answer (score 1):

You could call the Algolia REST API directly.

Some references:

- [Making HTTP requests from NativeScript](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/11/make-http-requests-in-a-nativescript-mobile-application/)
- [Algolia REST API documentation](https://www.algolia.com/doc/rest-api/search/)

(Note: Algolia doesn't usually recommend using the REST API directly because the API clients contain some DNS-related failover logic. If you are creating a large, high-availability production app, this is something to keep in mind.)